# Letsencrypt how to use --preferred-challenges

Tags: lets-encrypt

This command:

```
$ letsencrypt certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns --email foo@bar.com --domains test001.bar.com
```

outputs:

```
letsencrypt: error: unrecognized arguments: --preferred-challenges dns
```

From the documentation here: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-command-line-options

I find:

```
  --preferred-challenges PREF_CHALLS
                        A sorted, comma delimited list of the preferred
                        challenge to use during authorization with the most
                        preferred challenge listed first (Eg, "dns" or "tls-
                        sni-01,http,dns"). Not all plugins support all
                        challenges. See
                        https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#plugins for
                        details. ACME Challenges are versioned, but if you
                        pick "http" rather than "http-01", Certbot will select
                        the latest version automatically. (default: [])
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the answer, although the website states that `letsencrypt` and `certbot` are the same. It seems to not be the case.

```
$ apt-get install letsencrypt
$ apt-get install python-pip
$ pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip install certbot
$ certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns --email foo@bar.com --domains test001.bar.com
```

Does the trick

Comment: I believe most of us are here because we need the dns challenge :-D